# How can I improve this 2000+ lines function in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to build a salary tax calculator based on official numbers and rules in my country and I have this ugly monstrosity function, thousands of lines long. I'm curious to learn how I can improve this function.

I want to make it:

- Shorter, less code
- Easily extensible. Next year we will get new numbers

Numbers and cities in the code below are just examples. The actual code has about 500 `if` statements and 290 `case` rows per `if` statement:

```
export const getTax = (salary: number, city: string): number => {
  if (salary >= 1701 && salary <= 1800) {
    switch (city) {
      case 'TOKYO': return 126;
      case 'PARIS': return 136;
      case 'LONDON': return 145;
      case 'MADRID': return 193;
      // and many more case rows
      default: return 112;
    }
  }
  if (salary >= 1801 && salary <= 1900) {
    switch (city) {
      case 'TOKYO': return 135;
      case 'PARIS': return 186;
      case 'LONDON': return 176;
      case 'MADRID': return 192;
      // and many more case rows
      default: return 143;
    }
  }
  if (salary >= 1901 && salary <= 2000) {
    switch (city) {
      case 'TOKYO': return 212;
      case 'PARIS': return 209;
      case 'LONDON': return 188;
      case 'MADRID': return 211;
      // and many more case rows
      default: return 244;
    }
  }
  // and maybe 500 more if statements
```

Comment: Are there not formulas for calculating the tax for each city?

Comment: What is the next step when the return number is obtained? Whats is the meaning of the actual numbers? Whithout a pattern, I believe there won't be much to change...

Comment: So this actually isn't code, it's representing table data? How did you even write this? Where did you get the numbers from?

Comment: As implied by Bergi's comment and CertainPerformance's answer, this is normally a use case for a database, rather than hard coding all such data. With a db, you could even have historisation, so you could easily  perform the computation for a past date if needed.

Comment: @Bergi I got the number as a multi page long PDF. I copy pasted them into Webstorm and did multiline-edits on it until I had wrapped everything in ifs and case. In any case. You are right that I should've fed this into a DB and handled it like that. I just wanted to build something with pure html/css/js dependencies..

Comment: @Weblurk I did not mean a database, but just a JSON file or array/object literal.

Answer (score 2):

If there was a formula for calculating the tax for a given salary in a given city, I would just make an object with those formulas as the value for each city and simply call the appropriate formula based on the city. e.g.

```js
taxes = {
  LONDON : (salary) => .1 * salary + 1000,
  TOKYO : (salary) => .5 * salary + 2455,
}

console.log(taxes['LONDON'](2500))
console.log(taxes['TOKYO'](2000))
```

Failing that, you could make an object of the salary and city tax values:

```js
const tax = {
  1800 : { TOKYO : 126, PARIS : 136, LONDON : 145, MADRID : 193, default : 112 },
  1900 : { TOKYO : 135, PARIS : 186, LONDON : 176, MADRID : 192, default : 143 },
  2000 : { TOKYO : 212, PARIS : 209, LONDON : 188, MADRID : 211, default : 244 }
}

const getTax = (salary, city) => {
  taxScale = tax[Object.keys(tax).find(k => k >= salary)]
  return taxScale?.[city] || taxScale.default
}

console.log(getTax(1830, 'LONDON'))
console.log(getTax(1966, 'MADRID'))
console.log(getTax(1348, 'NEW YORK'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the long data in the JavaScript. Put it in a CSV spreadsheet instead, and then parse the spreadsheet in order to construct the `getTax` function. For example, with a spreadsheet like

```
          1701-1800   1801-1900   1901-2000
TOKYO     126         135         212
PARIS     136         186         209
LONDON    145         176         188
```

You could use something like the [node-csv](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv) package, and with the `parse` function, you'd get an array of arrays similar to

```
[
  ['', '1701-1800', '1801-1900', '1901-2000'],
  ['TOKYO', 126, 135, 212],
  ['PARIS', 136, 186, 209],
  ...
]
```

And then construct the conditions from that, something like:

```
const amountByCity = Object.fromEntries(
  data.slice(1).map(([city, ...amounts]) => [city, amounts])
);
const ranges = data[0].slice(1).map(str => str.split('-').map(Number));
const getTax = (salary, city) => {
  const rangeIndex = ranges.findIndex((lower, upper) => salary >= lower && salary <= upper);
  return amountByCity[city]?.[rangeIndex] ?? amountByCity['default'][rangeIndex];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like that ?

```js
cityVal = 
  { '1701-1800': { default: 112, TOKYO: 126, PARIS: 136, LONDON: 145, MADRID: 193 }
  , '1801-1900': { default: 143, TOKYO: 135, PARIS: 186, LONDON: 176, MADRID: 192 }
  , '1901-2000': { default: 244, TOKYO: 212, PARIS: 209, LONDON: 188, MADRID: 211 }
//...
  }

const getTax = (salary,  city ) => 
  {
  let range = Object.keys(cityVal).find( k =>
      {
      let [min,max] = k.split('-').map(Number)
      return (salary >= min && salary <= max)  
      })
  // if (!range) throw error no range on this salary...
  
  return cityVal[range][city] || cityVal[range].default
  }


// test 
console.log( getTax(1850,'LONDON')  )  // 176
console.log( getTax(1850,'xxx')  )     // 143
```